# Simple barista application to calculate the price of a drink based on different ingredients

Tags: java, enum

The scenario is that a customer orders a coffee from a vending machine by selecting a choice from several categories, 
such as size, flavor, and creamer type.

Given their choices, we then have to figure out the cost.

The twist is that the various creamer choices cost slightly more if you get an extra-large coffee.

For example, if you choose milk as your creamer, 
it is normally 50 cents; 
but, if you also choose XL as your size, the milk costs 60 cents.

```
public enum Coffee {

    CAFFEE_AMERICANO("Coffee", .75),
    CAFFEE_LATTE("Caffee Latte" , .50),
    CAFFE_MOCHA("Caffee Mocha" , .65),
    CAPPUCCINO("Cappuccino" , .85),
    COFFEE("Caffee" , .95),
    DECAF_COFFEE("Decaf Coffee" , .45);

    private final String name;
    private final double unit_price;

    private Coffee(String name, double unit_cost)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.unit_price = unit_cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getUnit_price() {
        return unit_price;
    }

}
```

---

```
public enum Creamer {

    NONE("None", 0.0),
    MILK("Milk", 0.50),
    HALF_N_HALF("Half and Half", 0.25),

    TALL_MILK("Milk", 0.60),
    TALL_HALF_N_HALF("Half and Half", 0.35),

    GRANDE_MILK("Grande Milk", 0.65),
    GRANDE_HALF_N_HALF("Grande Half and Half", 0.45),

    VENTI_MILK("Venti Milk", 0.70),
    VENTI_HALF_N_HALF("Venti Half and Half", 0.55),

    TRENTA_MILK("Trenta Milk", 0.75),
    TRENTA_HALF_N_HALF("Trenta Half and Half", 0.60);


    private String name;
    private double price;

    private Creamer(String name, double price)
    {
        this.name= name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class PricingEngine {

    public static double priceBasedOnSize(Map<String, Enum> ingredients) {

        double totalCost = 0.0;
        Coffee coffee = (Coffee) ingredients.get("Coffee");
        totalCost += coffee.getUnit_price();

        Size size = (Size) ingredients.get("Size");

        Creamer creamer = (Creamer) ingredients.get("Creamer");

        // get price based on the creamer and cup size

        String priceBySize = size.name() + "_" + creamer.name();

        totalCost += Creamer.valueOf(priceBySize).getPrice();

        return totalCost;

    }

}
```

---

```
public enum Size {

    TALL("Tall"),
    GRANDE("Grande"),
    VENTI("Venti"),
    TRENTA("Trenta");

    private String name;

    private Size(String name)
    {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name();
    }

}
```

---

```
public class BaristaMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean appRunning = true;
        Map<String, Enum> map = new HashMap<String, Enum>();
        System.out.println("Welcome to automatic coffee dispensing service\n\n");
        while (appRunning) {

            System.out.print("1. Caffe Americano");
            System.out.print(" 2. Caffe Latte");
            System.out.print(" 3. Caffe Mocha");
            System.out.print(" 4. Cappuccino");
            System.out.print(" 5. Coffee");
            System.out.println(" 6. Decaf Coffee");
            System.out.println("Please enter your choice: ");
            int chioiceOfCoffee = in.nextInt();

            if (chioiceOfCoffee == 1) {
                map.put("Coffee", Coffee.CAFFEE_AMERICANO);

            } else if (chioiceOfCoffee == 2) {
                map.put("Coffee", Coffee.CAFFEE_LATTE);

            } else if (chioiceOfCoffee == 3) {
                map.put("Coffee", Coffee.CAFFE_MOCHA);

            } else if (chioiceOfCoffee == 4) {
                map.put("Coffee", Coffee.CAPPUCCINO);

            } else if (chioiceOfCoffee == 5) {
                map.put("Coffee", Coffee.COFFEE);

            } else if (chioiceOfCoffee == 6) {
                map.put("Coffee", Coffee.DECAF_COFFEE);

            } else {
                System.out.println("Your entry: " + chioiceOfCoffee + " is not valide. Please enter a valid choice.");
            }

            System.out.print("1. Tall(Slept 8-10 Hours)");
            System.out.print(" 2. Grande(Slept 5-7 Hours)");
            System.out.print(" 3. Venti(Slept 0-4 Hours");
            System.out.println(" 4. Trenta(WTF is sleep?)");
            System.out.println("Please enter your cup size: ");
            int cupSize = in.nextInt();

            if (cupSize == 1) {
                map.put("Size", Size.TALL);

            } else if (cupSize == 2) {
                map.put("Size", Size.GRANDE);

            } else if (cupSize == 3) {
                map.put("Size", Size.VENTI);

            } else if (cupSize == 4) {
                map.put("Size", Size.TRENTA);

            } else {
                System.out.println(
                    "Your entry for cup size : " + cupSize + " is not valide. Please enter a valid choice.");
            }

            System.out.print("1. NONE");
            System.out.print(" 2. MILK");
            System.out.println(" 3. HALF_N_HALF");
            System.out.println("Please enter your choice of creamer: ");
            int creamer = in.nextInt();

            if (creamer == 1) {
                map.put("Creamer", Creamer.NONE);

            } else if (creamer == 2) {
                map.put("Creamer", Creamer.MILK);

            } else if (creamer == 3) {
                map.put("Creamer", Creamer.HALF_N_HALF);

            } else {
                System.out.println(
                    "Your entry for cup size : " + cupSize + " is not valide. Please enter a valid choice.");
            }

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Dispensing.............");

            System.out.println("Total Cost: " + PricingEngine.priceBasedOnSize(map));
            System.out.println("Enjoy your coffee!");

        }

    }

}
```

I know there are 5 other ways (such as decorator pattern) to do this but for some reasons the solution has to have enum.

Let me know what you guys think about this solution. Any improvement on the pricing engine will be helpful.

There can be other categories as well that can change the price of the coffee.

Comment: `...for some reasons the solution has to have enum...` could you elaborate on this, it seems like an artificial constraint, and the constraint may also affect answers

Answer (score 6):

## General Implementation

I would lean towards having a Priceable interface, which the extra enums implement, and having the coffee storing a list of extras, which can be passed the size and return the amount to add to the price.

```
enum Creamer implements Priceable {
    NONE {
        @Override
        public double getPrice(Size size) {
            return 0;
        }
    }, MILK {
        @Override
        public double getPrice(Size size) {
            switch (size) {
                case TALL:
                    return 0.6;
                case GRANDE:
                    return 0.65;
                case VENTI:
                    return 0.70;
                case TRENTA:
                    return 0.75;
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError("Unknown size");
            }
        }
    }, HALF_N_HALF {
        @Override
        public double getPrice(Size size) {
            switch (size) {
                case TALL:
                    return 0.35;
                case GRANDE:
                    return 0.45;
                case VENTI:
                    return 0.50;
                case TRENTA:
                    return 0.6;
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError("Unknown size");
            }
        }
    };
}

interface Priceable {
    public double getPrice(Size size);
}
```

## Use of double for money

I would try to use int instead of double if possible, so that you do not have to deal with floating point issues.

## Input validation

At the moment an exception is thrown if the user makes bad input, you probably want to handle this instead.

## Using ordinals

Using the `values()` array you can avoid having to switch over the enum members to get them by index.

Comment: loved your idea to move towards interface. Much cleaner approach. I made few changes to reflect those changes.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for sharing your code.

I like the `enum` approach but it could be improved.

My problem with your approach is that you handle the drink size like an ingredient.

On the other hand you separate the "XL" price of the creamer from the creamer itself where it might be a property of the creamer.

So I'd create a common interface for the coffee types and the creamers, so that I can hold them in the same List:

```
interface Ingredient{
  /** @return the ingredient price depending on the drinks size */
  double getPrice(Size size);
}
```

The creamer `enum` implements this interface:

```
enum Creamer implements Ingredient {
    NONE("None"){
       @override
       public double getPrice(Size size){
           return 0.0; // same value for all
       }
    },
    MILK("Milk", 0.50, 0.65, 0.70, 0.75),
    HALF_N_HALF("Half and Half", 0.25, 0.45, 0.55, 0.60);

    private final double[] prices;
    private final String name;
    Creamer(String name, double ... prices){
      this.name = name;
      this.prices = prices;
    }
    @override
    public double getPrice(Size size){
       return prices[size.ordinal()]; // enum Size should have a dedicated getIndex() method to be independent from order in the enum.
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

The my coffee type type will also implement this interface since it no problem for the implementer to ignore the size parameter. Also it makes it easy to introduce size depended prices for the coffees too, but this is a side effect, not intended:

```
enum Coffe implements Ingredient {

    CAFFEE_AMERICANO("Coffee", .75),
    CAFFEE_LATTE("Caffee Latte" , .50),
    CAFFE_MOCHA("Caffee Mocha" , .65),
    CAPPUCCINO("Cappuccino" , .85),
    COFFEE("Caffee" , .95),
    DECAF_COFFEE("Decaf Coffee" , .45);

    private final String name;
    private final double unitPrice;

    private Coffee(String name, double unitCost)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.unitPrice = unitCost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @override
    public double gePrice(Size size) {
        return unitPrice;
    }
}
```

Having this I can collect coffee and creamer in a `Collection<Ingredient>`  (rather than in a `Map`) and pass this list along with the selected size to the `PricingEngine`:

```
// ...
Collection<Ingredient> myCoffee = new HasSet<>();
myCoffee.add(askForCoffeeType());
int size = askForSize();
myCoffee.add(askForCreamer());

double coffeePrice = new PricingEngine()
                      .priceBasedOnSize(myCoffee, size);
reportToCustomer(coffeePrice);
// ...
```

.

```
public class PricingEngine {

    public static double priceBasedOnSize(Collection<Ingredient> ingredients, int size) {
        double totalCost = 0.0;
        for(Ingredient ingredient : ingredients)
            totalCost += ingredient.getPrice(size);
        return totalCost;
        // alternative with Java8
        return ingredients.stram().
                          .mapToDouble(ingredient.getPrice(size))
                          .sum();
    }

}
```

Benefit:

- no differentiation between coffee and creamer.
- shorter
- supports more ingredient types (e.g. optional "flavors") without change. But again: this is a side effect, not intended.